# Are bricks technically a type of pottery?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The Merriam-Webster dictionary gives the following as the third definition of the word "pottery":

> CLAYWARE -
> especially : earthenware as distinguished from porcelain and stoneware and from brick and tile

It defines "clayware" as "articles made of fired clay."

Bricks are (or at least many are) made of fired clay. Do such bricks count as "pottery"? I understand the "especially" part, but does "especially" here indicate common usage (i.e., most people usually mean it this way) or technical meaning (technicians and linguists would consider this distinction fundamental to the word).

Comment: The definition says 'as distinguished from porcelain... AND from brick and tile', so it obviously doesn't  count bricks as pottery.

Comment: @KateBunting My question is really about what "especially" means here. If the definition had not included "clayware - especially:", I'd agree there'd have been no ambiguity. Their definition of "salt" includes "especially to season or preserve food or in industry", which is neither technically accurate in general (not all salts, though they do assume NaCl) nor is it exhaustive (NaCl has other common uses) nor is it exclusive (other things are used to season and preserve food).

Comment: It indicates common usage. The _usual_ meaning of 'pottery' is 'earthenware as opposed to china', the usual meaning of 'salt' in everyday speech is sodium chloride, thought of as being commonly used for those purposes. The definition isn't intended to cover all salts (that's covered by their definition **d**), and the existence of other seasonings is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the various online dictionary entries for 'pottery' such as [the Lexico one](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pottery)
And the definition given on websites and blogs run by and for potters such as [this one](https://nomliving.com/blogs/thingswedo/pottery-and-ceramics-a-brief-explanation) you will find a high degree of consenus on the idea that 'pottery' as a mass noun refers mainly to items which are containers, although some (such as the blog under the link above) have wider definitions like

> Both pottery and ceramic are general terms that describe objects which have been formed with clay, hardened by firing and decorated or glazed.

Items which are considered by the sources using tighter definitions not to be pottery include ceramic art objects such as figurines and articles like fine art vases which, although they are containers, are primarily beautiful objects.

Bricks, tiles and pipes are certainly ceramics as are pieces of sanitaryware like handbasins and toilets, since they are usually  made from clay and fired, but bricks and tiles aren't containers or, usually art objeacts, Decorative glazed tiles can be art objects but roof tiles are not. Pipes aren't containers either since they are designed so that liquids can flow though them rather than be retained and sanitaryware doesn't bear much resemblance to the sort of domestic utensil normally called 'a pot'

Given that bricks and roof tiles are not containers and not decorative objects they are not 'pottery' by most definitions even though they are utilitarian ceramic objects. By extension clay pipes and sanitaryware aren't 'pottery' either by most definitions.

Comment: Even the Lexico article includes the phrase "and other articles"... I'd agree is common usage "pottery" is not commonly understood to include bricks and other things, I find it curious that the definitions I'm seeing don't definitively exclude bricks. Does anybody (correctly) refer to bricks as a kind of pottery? I doubt it but am not sure.

Comment: @Patrick87 Taking the practitioner-derived definitions of 'pottery' as a guide I would take the Lexico definition to mean items like earthenware figurines, other decorative objects and practical but independent items like door stops. As I said decorative wall and floor tiles can be considered 'pottery' because they are decorated and glazed but calling structural items like bricks and tiles 'pottery' just because they are coarse ceramics doesn't fit with a potter's idea of pottery. Not only that but brick and roof tile makers have not, traditionally, been called 'potters'.